# Unable to submit form with button outside of content (Ionic 4)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I use a modal to display a form and in the header of the modal I have a 'Done' button which I use to submit the form. Because this button is in the header tags and the form is in the content tags I use ngForm like this to submit the form...

```
<ion-header>

<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-button color="primary" (click)="goBack()">Back</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
        <ion-button color="primary" [disabled]="!profileForm.dirty || !profileForm.valid" (click)="goBack()">Save</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Profil</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

```
<ion-content color="medium" *ngIf="logged">

<form #profileForm="ngForm" name="profileForm" id="profileForm" novalidate>
```

```
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('profileForm') form: NgForm;
```

**Expected Behavior**
Users should be able to submit a form with an ion-button outside of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use a reactive form, you wouldn't have this problem at all ;) I strongly suggest you would do that! But here's a solution for your current issue.

So, your code would actually work, if you were not to have `*ngIf`. Structural directives scope template reference variables to just what's inside that structural directive, since angular actually creates a separate template for that. But since you are using `@ViewChild` to get a hold of that template reference, that is what you can use in your code. So change...

```html
<ion-button [disabled]="!profileForm.dirty || !profileForm.valid" (click)="save()">
```

to...

```html
<ion-button [disabled]="!form?.dirty || !form?.valid" (click)="save()">
```

We need to use the safe navigation operator, since when template is rendered, we do not yet have access to the `form` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your view so that the button is in form:

```
<form>
    <ion-header>
       //submit button here
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
       //form here
    </ion-content>
</form>
```

Or just do whatever you need to do in `(click)` handler of the 'Save' button.